# How do I join multiple tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The case:

tables:

1. `teacher :id  :name`
2. `course  :id  :name`
3. `teachercourse  :id  :teacher_id  :course_id`

How to do inner join to this 3 tables with rails?

**Edit** (my models):

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :teachercourses
  has_many :teachers, through: :teachercourse
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :teachercourses
  has_many :courses, through: :teachercourse
end

class Teachercourse < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course_id, :teacher_id
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

**Edit2** - where I need the join result(show action):

```
class CourseController < ApplicationController
  def show
    #not real syntax
    @course=Course.find(join:teacher,teachercourse,teacher :: where course='javacourse');
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you expect get from this query?

Comment: expect to get:course name, teacher name

Comment: You might well be better of with [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many), unless you really need `Teachercourse` as a model in its own right.

Comment: A better name for `Teachercourse` model might be `Instructorship` or `Professorship`, but as Chowlett said, you might not need model unless you need to associate additional information to this resource.

Comment: this is just simple example of my big code, i just need sqlQuery for that example - i will do same in rel code. like Course.find(....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your Teacher and Course models should also contain `has_many :teachercourses`

Then, if you're writing your code in the Teacher model it should be something like this:

```
joins(teachercourses: :course)
```

Edit:

If I understand the intention behind the code you posted, you're looking for all the teachers that teach in the java course. So this should work:

```
Teacher.joins(teachercourses: :course).where(course: {name: "javacourse"})
```

Comment: thanks, i add has_many :teachercourses. Can you please write the rails join - i am new and don't know the syntax

Comment: I am writing my code in Controller that need 3 table join result

Comment: The syntax in the answer is the real syntax for the join. If you can share the code where you want to use it I can adjust.

Comment: thanks! Teacher.joins(teachercourses: :course).where(courses: {name: "javacourse"})  the query works, but why the result not contain course.name? only teacher id, teacher name .

Comment: If you want the result to contain the course names you should replace 'joins' with 'includes'